# Returning css formatted coldfusion results with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, coldfusion

Okay, so I did this jquery, and the results come back fine, but the css doesn't get applied. Is there a way to apply css to the results?

```
function doSearch() {
//Send the AJAX call to the server
  $.ajax({
  //The URL to process the request
    'url' : 'cf/inventoryQuery.cfm',
  //The type of request, also known as the "method" in HTML forms
  //Can be 'GET' or 'POST'
    'type' : 'POST',
  //Any post-data/get-data parameters
  //This is optional
    'data' : $("#SearchInventory").serialize(),
  //The response from the server
    'success' : function(data) {
        $('#Results').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

EDIT - This is the div that gets the new contents

```
<div id="Results" >
    <cfoutput query="queryCars" maxrows="4">
        <div class="Result">
            <img src="images/samplecar.png"  />
            <div class="ResultText">
               #strYear# #strMake# #strModel#
        </div>
        </div>
    </cfoutput>
</div>
```

The results returned from the AJAX call look like this

```
    <cfoutput query="queryCars" maxrows="4">
        <div class="Result">
            <img src="images/samplecar.png"  />
            <div class="ResultText">
                #strYear# #strMake# #strModel#
         </div>
        </div>
    </cfoutput>
```

So it's literally replacing one thing with the exact same thing. My calling page has a 

in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ajax call looks like it is returning HTML from CF.  So basically, you have 2 options.

1. generate the css inside a `<style>` tag and return it along side with your query table.
2. include the css file in your caller page, and make sure the generated result from your `.cfm` uses the same predefined classes.

Comment: That's the thing that is confusing - The page that calls this is replacing a div with new query results - The items put inside the div have all the same classes.

Comment: I included the style tag like you recommended. Works great.